# Return to libc finding pointers

Tags: c, gdb

For a class in software security I've got to make a simple return to libc attack. I managed to make a perl script that completes the attack given the correct pointers to system(), exit() and the /bin/sh string. I found these pointers using gdb "p system" etc. Now I want to make the exploit a bit more "dynamic" by writing a c program that finds the adres of system() and exit() at run time. How do I do this? I tried "&system" but that doesn't seem to be giving me the correct adress at all.

Edit:
The system does NOT have ASLR enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may easily find the addresses using `binutils` - `objdump` or `readelf`, but **only addresses of the symbols the binary is actually using**. The unused symbols are not linked with the libc library.

Say you want to hack the `ls` command:

```
objdump -d `which ls` | less
```

you will find this section:

```
0000000000402910 <exit@plt>:
  402910:       ff 25 da 89 21 00       jmpq   *0x2189da(%rip)        # 61b2f0 <_fini+0x208704>
  402916:       68 5e 00 00 00          pushq  $0x5e
  40291b:       e9 00 fa ff ff          jmpq   402320 <_init+0x10>
```

So now you have the address: `0x402910` is the jump address of the `exit()` function (the one you would get printed if you tried `printf("%x\n", exit);`.

Regarding `system`, `ls` is not using this symbol so you cannot access it this way, as it is not linked.

Comment: If it isn't a library entry point, then it must be defined somewhere. The C standard required it to be define as a function so it must exist somewhere. Try finding it.

Comment: @randomusername I updated my answer - now I know exactly how to find the address of the function. But, **the symbol/function you want to call must be already used by the binary you want to hack.** Otherwise, it is not linked.

Comment: @randomusername a process will also end if main returns... there is no special function for that... you just ran out of program. if a symbol isnt used it isnt required to be in the object file anywhere. and if it isnt compiled in you would have to dynamically link at run time... which is of limited utility, because the program isnt using it and you are already executing arbitrary code at that point..

Answer (score 2):

ASCII Armoring is enabled by default on some popular Linux distros. It generally maps adresses of important libraries to a memory range containing NULL byte. You can read more about how to bypass ASCII Armoring [here.](http://www.exploit-db.com/download_pdf/17286/)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to write a program in C that will execute and exploit a vulnerable userspace program? In that case, if you're program written in C is using execve(), then that will start the vulnerable process with it's own process-space. This will include libc loaded anew. Think of it like this:

```
pwner
 `-[libc]
 `-./vuln
    `-[libc]
```

In this instance, your dynamic program, 'pwner' will need to use something like the ptrace() syscall to trace the vulnerable program and obtain libc pointers. This is effectively what GDB does as well when it is debugging a binary. Your program should use the ELF specification to find the address of E_ENTRY. From here use ptrace(). First with PTRACE_TRACEME and then PTRACE_PEEKTEXT.

Answer (score 0):

I think `&system` will be resolved at compile time. Have you tried `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`? Just suggestions, I don't know if they'll work.

**Edit**

None of them will work outside of target process context if some sort of [Address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is in place.